# Problem with HTML tabindex

Tags: html

Following is a sample code of which I’m working of. When navigating through ENTER button form submit invokes “Cancel” action though it’s tab index is after the “Next” button.

E.g.

```
Field01 <ENTER>  Field02 <ENTER>  Field03 <ENTER>   >>>>>  Form submits with Cancel action  
Field01 <TAB>    Field02 <TAB>    Field03 <TAB>     >>>>>  Next button is focused
```

Changing the order of “submit” buttons in HTML mark-up would help to prevent the invocation of “Cancel” button by default. But I need to keep “Cancel” button in left side & “Next” button in right side.

---

```
    <form  method="post" action="/SVRWeb/ActionController" name="frmMain">
        <div>
            <h1>Some information</h1>
            <label>Field 01</label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="0" name="field01" value""  size="15" />
            <label>Field 02</label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="field02" value""  size="15" />
            <label>Field 03</label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="2" name="field03" value""  size="15" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" tabindex="4" name="Action.User.Init" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="submit" tabindex="3" name="Action.User.Form2" value="Next"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: As a side note, your first tab index should be 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enter key fires the firstnext `type="submit"` element in the form, regardless of the tabindex. There are two ways to go around this:

1. Use JS to click the particular button when enter key is pressed:

   ```
   <form onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('next').click();">
   ```

   This however get nasty when you've a `<textarea>` in the form for which you of course want to keep its default behaviour with enter key.
2. Put buttons in same container element with the *Next* button first and use CSS to swap them.

   ```
   .next { float: right; }
   .cancel { float: left; }
   ```

Comment: does the keycode event work in all major browsers? I faintly remember having trouble with this in firefox.

Comment: @nick: there are indeed browser specific behaviours. Learn more here for the case that you encounter this problem in the future: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it see's the Cancel and Next button as the same thing. They are both of type Submit. So when you press enter it finds the first submit button. I would change the cancel type to maybe reset? Then use javascript/jQuery to do a redirect when you click the cancel button.
There may be a better way.